# How to find the default page name

Tags: asp.net

I am working on the css of a website, I would like to know which page is the default page (The one that opens when I run th eapplication). There is no Index or Default. Is there any way to find it from browser or project properties?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core? If it's MVC or Core, you'll probably find the HTML under a directory named `Views` and by default the site root home page is at`Views\Home\Index.cshtml` with the common `<head>` content inside a file named `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: I am told that it is MVC, I searched for views or controllers, The application is consist of modules from another app so the structure doesn't look like a normal MVC. That is why i was looking for a way to find it from any where except explorer.

Comment: The default is configured in the compiled code in the routing definition, it's not visible unless you have access to the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core? If it's MVC or Core, you'll probably find the HTML under a directory named Views and by default the site root home page is atViews\Home\Index.cshtml with the common  content inside a file named Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml. – Dai May 10 at 19:10